# How to select rows from a pandas df based on index values between two numbers

Tags: python, pandas

How would I select rows 2 through 4 of the following df to get the desired output shown below.
I tried to do `df = df.index.between(2,4)` but I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'between'`

```
    col 1   col 2   col 3
0   1   1   2
1   5   4   2
2   2   1   5
3   1   2   2
4   3   2   4
5   4   3   2
```

Desired output

```
    col 1   col 2   col 3
2   2   1   5
3   1   2   2
4   3   2   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `loc` for index selection using label slicing:

```
df.loc[2:4]
```

Output:

```
   col 1  col 2  col 3
2      2      1      5
3      1      2      2
4      3      2      4
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to select rows from a dataframe is to use the .iloc[rows, columns] function pandas for example here i select lines 2 to 4

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"b":[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df1.iloc[1:3] #
```

Answer (score 0):

With loc

```
min=2
max=4
between_range= range(min, max+1,1)
df.loc[between_range]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
df.iloc[2:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use .iloc[rows,columns]

`df.iloc[2:4, :]`

Answer (score 0):

[`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) cannot act on an index datatypes but just on a `Series`. So, if you want to use a boolean mask you first need to convert the index to a series using [`to_series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html#pandas.Index.to_series) like this:

```
df
#    col1  col2  col3
# 0     1     1     2
# 1     5     4     2
# 2     2     1     5
# 3     1     2     2
# 4     3     2     4
# 5     4     3     2

df[df.index.to_series().between(2,4)]
#    col1  col2  col3
# 2     2     1     5
# 3     1     2     2
# 4     3     2     4
```